# Prevent sub-section nesting in Python Sphinx when using toctree

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, toctree

I'm running into a problem in structuring my Sphinx users guide. I would like to form a chapter by having a main landing page (index.rst) that contains the chapter heading and an overview, and then separate sub-sections contained in different files(part1.rst, part2.rst). I am trying to use "toctree" to insert the separate subsections, but I am running into a nesting problem where my toctree is getting sucked into my overview section. (note: I am not using the `..include::` directive because I want the sub-sections displayed on different web pages sequentially linked. I also want the structured properly so they lay out nicely in the pdf rendered version of the UG).

**index.rst**

> ```
> Chapter 3                                                
> ===============================                                                 
>
> Overview                                                                        
> --------                                                                        
>
> Yadda yadda yadda.
>
> .. toctree::                                                                    
>    :hidden:                                                                     
>
>    part1                                                                        
>    part2
> ```

**part1.rst**

> ```
> Part 1
> ------
>
> This part is all about yadda.
> ```

**part2.rst**

> ```
> Part 2
> ------
>
> More yadda.
> ```

I would like the resulting structure to be:

> ```
> Chapter 3
>   - overview
>   - part 1
>   - part 2
> ```

But what I'm getting is

> ```
> Chapter 3
>   - overview
>     - part 1
>     - part 2
> ```

It seems like the toctree I include at the bottom of the file is falling under the "overview" section, instead of being run under the main chapter context. I tried inserting the toctree at the top of the file, but then I get this ordering:

> ```
> Chapter 3
>   - part 1
>   - part 2
>   - overview
> ```

It seems like there must be a way to do this properly, but I haven't been able to find anything on the Sphinx site or here on SO. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is an RST/`docutils` problem, not a sphinx problem. It seems that there is no way to specify "now go back under the previous heading level" in rst, other than by creating a new heading. By design, sphinx constructs the toc-tree by inserting the headings in the location where the toctree is. So sphinx isn't really in the wrong here.

Comment: I've made a PR to let sphinx work around this: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/3622

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same problem, and couldn't find a nice solution.  The only options seemed to be either remove the sub-heading ('Overview' in the example above) or mark it up as a rubric, e.g.

```
.. rubric:: Overview
```

which means it doesn't get included in the TOC.  It should be possible to apply styling to the rubric so it looks like a sub-heading, but doing it this way feels like a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 1):

For the latex pdf generator, you could sneek in overview as a same-level heading like this:

```
.. raw:: latex

    \chapter{Overview}
```