# Listing local sections first, linked pages last in TOC

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, tableofcontents, toctree

Let's say I have the following `index.rst`:

```
Some global topic
=====================

.. toctree::
  :glob:

  nested/index

Global topic introduction
------------------------
```

And `nested/index.rst`:

```
Some sub-topic
==============
```

I want TOC to be like:

- Some global topic

  - Global topic introduction
  - Some sub-topic

Instead, I get the following:

- Some global topic

  - Some sub-topic
  - Global topic introduction

How to make local sections appear first, and linked pages after them?

Comment: And of course, putting the `toctree` at the bottom of the page [causes this to nest under the introduction](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25276415/102441) instead...

Comment: I've made a PR concerning this, but it won't fix your case (no `:hidden:` by choice. If you want that to change, please make an argument at https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/3622.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect solution, but how about

```
.. contents::
   :local:

.. toctree::       
   :glob:
    nested/index
```

That will give you:

- Some global topic

  - Global topic introduction
- Some sub-topic

Comment: Nah, that will not look good for my documentation. My example is simplified, actually I have multi-level nesting. I think I was getting result similar to yours by just manually listing documents in some top-level page's TOC and wasn't satisfied with it.