# Remove redundant toctree from sidebar in sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sidebar, restructuredtext, toctree

Edit: [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276415/prevent-sub-section-nesting-in-python-sphinx-when-using-toctree?rq=1) seems related

I am using the [fulltoc](https://sphinxcontrib-fulltoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) extension to display the table of contents in the sidebar.

The global table of contents is defined in the global index.rst file. It is actually composed of a series of `toctree`s basically:

```
.. toctree::
   :caption: Getting Started

   gettingStarted/overview
   gettingStarted/section1
   gettingStarted/section2

.. toctree::
   :caption: Next Large section

   group2/overview
   group2/section1
   group2/etc
```

The `overview.rst` contains a description of each section and a toctree of the sections that follow. In the folder `gettingStarted` this file looks like:

```
Overview
========

This is a description of the section.

.. toctree::

   section1
   section2
```

The problem is that when looking at the page `gettingStarted/overview` the sidebar displays the sub-toc, which makes redundant entries:

> Getting Started
>
> - Overview
>
>   - section1
>   - section2
> - section1
> - section2

where I would rather have

> Getting Started
>
> - Overview
> - section1
> - section2

One work around is to lower the `:maxdepth:`, but then the sidebar won't expand sub-sections when reading from a section (such as gettingStarted/section1).

I also found the [`rubric`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/para.html#directive-rubric) directive but cannot figure out how to make it work on a `toctree`.

How can I prevent the sub-TOCs from being indexed into the global TOC?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sphinx-remove-toctrees`, available on PyPI.

```
pip install sphinx-remove-toctrees
```

The documentation can be found on the GitHub: https://github.com/executablebooks/sphinx-remove-toctrees
All you have to do is create a list `remove_from_toctrees` which contains global expression of pages to remove from the sidebar, e.g.

```
remove_from_toctrees = ["generated/api/*"]
```

Note that the paths are platform dependent, at least until this PR is merged: https://github.com/executablebooks/sphinx-remove-toctrees/pull/4

Or you can install from my fork for now:

```
sphinx-remove-toctrees @ git+https://github.com/mscheltienne/sphinx-remove-toctrees
```